# Improving a longtable - Underfull \vbox and Overfull \hbox

Tags: longtable, multicolumn

I made a table using *longtable* and *multicolumn* packages. My idea is to spread the table to \textwidth , use **n** number of columns with the same width and use chunk of the \textwidth for each row.
*tabularx* is not an option because it produces error when using \kill. More info if someone is interested [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583484/xltabular-produces-error-in-combination-with-multicolumn-and-kill)

*Longtabu* is also not an option because is no longer maintained.

What I am missing in the calculations for columns width ?
Is there a better way to do this report (with the same layout output) ?
Any help is welcomed :)

MWE

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=18pt]{article}

   \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{
    % verbose,
    portrait,       % page orientation (landscape or portrait)
    a4paper,        % paper size
    tmargin=5mm,    % page top margin
    bmargin=5mm,    % page bottom margin
    lmargin=5mm,   % page left margin
    rmargin=5mm % page right maring
}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[defaultsans]{opensans} %font
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,bulgarian]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{layouts}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}   

\definecolor{greyCell}{RGB}{235,235,235}
\newcommand{\smf}{ % small font
    \fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont
}
\begin{document}

\def\arraystretch{1}%  vertical padding
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.8mm} % for the horizontal padding
\fontsize{10}{13}\selectfont 


          
           \vspace{-4mm}
            \noindent
                
      \LTleft=0pt 
      \LTright=0pt
    \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{20}{p{0.5\textwidth}} @{}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{20}{|p{\dimexpr 1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}{ \centering \textbf{ Платежна бележка } }\\ % header
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{ \smf Период } & % ---------------- row 1
    \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{  } & 
    \multicolumn{6}{p{\dimexpr 0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{ \smf 2020.07 } & 
    \multicolumn{3}{p{\dimexpr 0.15\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{ \smf Календар } & 
    \multicolumn{7}{p{\dimexpr 0.35\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}{ \smf 5 Пет дневна работна седмица } \\ 
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{ \smf За лице } & % ---------------- row 2
    \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{ \smf\raggedleft\arraybackslash 146 } & 
    \multicolumn{6}{p{\dimexpr 0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{ \smf Атанас Антонов Атанасов } & 
    \multicolumn{3}{p{\dimexpr 0.15\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{ \smf Работни дни } & 
    \multicolumn{7}{p{\dimexpr 0.35\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}{ \smf 23 } \\ 
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{ \smf Заето в } & % ---------------- row 3
    \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{ \smf\raggedleft\arraybackslash 12 } & 
    \multicolumn{6}{p{\dimexpr 0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{ \smf Поддръжка } & 
    \multicolumn{3}{p{\dimexpr 0.15\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{ \smf Трудов стаж } & 
    \multicolumn{7}{p{\dimexpr 0.35\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}{ \smf 24г. 1м. 4д. към 01.07.2020 } \\ 
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{ \smf Длъжност } & % ---------------- row 4
    \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{ \smf\raggedleft\arraybackslash 24236003 } & 
    \multicolumn{6}{p{\dimexpr 0.3\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{ \smf Експерт, организация на труда } & 
    \multicolumn{3}{p{\dimexpr 0.15\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}{ \smf Осн. заплата } & 
    \multicolumn{7}{p{\dimexpr 0.35\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}|}{ \smf 1,000.00 } \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{10}{|p{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}|}{ \smf \centering \cellcolor{greyCell} \textbf{ Начисления } } &
    \multicolumn{10}{p{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}|}{ \smf \centering \cellcolor{greyCell} \textbf{ Удръжки } } \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \centering \textit{шифър} } &
    \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \centering \textit{Наименование} } &
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \centering \textit{Сума} } &
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \centering \textit{д\%} } &
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \centering \textit{шифър} } &
    \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \centering \textit{Наименование} } &
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \centering \textit{Сума} } &
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}|}{ \smf \centering \textit{д\%} } \\ \hline 
                                  \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft  } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedright От 01.07.2020 г. ОМВ } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 1,000.00 } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 0 } &
                        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 455 } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedright Разпл. сметка Уникредит } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 777.20 } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}|}{ \smf \raggedleft 0 } \\ \hline
                                           \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 104 } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedright Заплата по щат } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 1,000.00 } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 23 } &
                        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 485 } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedright Разпл. сметка FiBank } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 75.00 } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}|}{ \smf \raggedleft 0 } \\ \hline
                                           \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 111 } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedright Допл.проф.опит и стаж } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 144.00 } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 14.4 } &
                        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 490 } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedright Банков заем } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 0.00 } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}|}{ \smf \raggedleft 0 } \\ \hline
                                       \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
                        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 500 } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedright Данък общ доход } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 98.63 } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}|}{ \smf \raggedleft 10 } \\ \hline
                                       \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
                        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 501 } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedright ЛОВ ф.\textquotedbl{}Безработица\textquotedbl{} } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 4.58 } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}|}{ \smf \raggedleft 0.4 } \\ \hline
                                       \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
                        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 533 } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedright ЛОВ ф.\textquotedbl{}Пенсии\textquotedbl{} } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 75.28 } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}|}{ \smf \raggedleft 6.58 } \\ \hline
                                       \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
                        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 536 } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedright ЛОВ ф.\textquotedbl{}ОЗМ\textquotedbl{} } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 16.02 } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}|}{ \smf \raggedleft 1.4 } \\ \hline
                                       \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
                        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 537 } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedright ЛОВ ф.\textquotedbl{}ДЗПО УПФ\textquotedbl{} } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 25.17 } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}|}{ \smf \raggedleft 2.2 } \\ \hline
                                       \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
                        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 540 } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedright Здравно осигуряване } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 36.61 } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}|}{ \smf \raggedleft 3.2 } \\ \hline
                                       \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{  } &
                        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 560 } &
        \multicolumn{5}{|p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedright Членски внос Подкрепа } &
        \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 35.50 } &
        \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}|}{ \smf \raggedleft 0 } \\ \hline
                    
    \multicolumn{7}{|p{\dimexpr 0.35\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf  \raggedright Всичко начисления } & % row 1 bottom
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 1,144.00 } & 
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ } &  
    \multicolumn{7}{|p{\dimexpr 0.35\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf  Всичко удръжки } & 
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft  1,144.00 } & 
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}|}{   }  \\  \hline 
    \multicolumn{7}{|p{\dimexpr 0.35\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf  \raggedright Осигурителен доход } & % row 2 bottom
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 1,144.00 } & 
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ } &  
    \multicolumn{7}{|p{\dimexpr 0.35\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf  Всичко за осигуреното лице } & 
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft  157.66 } & 
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}|}{   }  \\  \hline 
    \multicolumn{7}{|p{\dimexpr 0.35\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf  \raggedright Облагаем доход } & % row 3 bottom
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 1,144.00 } & 
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ } &  
    \multicolumn{7}{|p{\dimexpr 0.35\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf  Всичко за осигурителя } & 
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft  224.44 } & 
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}|}{   }  \\  \hline 
    \multicolumn{7}{|p{\dimexpr 0.35\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf  \raggedright Данъчна основа } & % row 4 bottom
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft 986.34 } & 
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ } &  
    \multicolumn{7}{|p{\dimexpr 0.35\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf  Сума за получаване } & 
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{\dimexpr 0.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}{ \smf \raggedleft  887.71 } & 
    \multicolumn{1}{|p{\dimexpr 0.05\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}|}{   }  \\  \hline 
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

**Result**
[image]

As David Carlisle said, this approach is overcomplicated. The table actually contains 8 columns (not 20) so I post this MWE provided by him.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    % verbose,
    portrait,       % page orientation (landscape or portrait)
    a4paper,        % paper size
    tmargin=5mm,    % page top margin
    bmargin=5mm,    % page bottom margin
    lmargin=5mm,   % page left margin
    rmargin=5mm % page right maring
}

% only needed with old latex installations 
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[defaultsans]{opensans} %font
    \usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{colortbl}
    \usepackage{longtable}

\definecolor{greyCell}{RGB}{235,235,235}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.8mm} % for the horizontal padding
\fontsize{10}{13}\selectfont 


\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}% keep hline away from text
\small
\LTleft=0pt
\LTright=0pt
        \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|*{8}{l|}@{}}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{\textbf{Header}}\\
        \multicolumn{4}{|l}{%
\begin{tabular}{lrl}
Label& &  2020.07\\
Label& 146 &long variable test\\
Label & 12 & variable variable variable\\
label  & 24568545 & long variable here
\end{tabular}}
&
        \multicolumn{4}{l|}{%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Label &  long variable \\ 
Label & 23\\
Label& Long variable long variable  \\  
Label & 1,000.12
\end{tabular}}
\\
\rowcolor{greyCell}
\multicolumn{4}{@{}|>{\columncolor{greyCell}[.8mm][2cm]}c@{}}{Label}&\multicolumn{4}{@{}c|@{}}{Label}\\
label&label&label&d\%&label&label&label&d\%\\\hline
104& long variable& 1,000.00&14.4&455&long variable&777.20&0,4\\\hline
111 & long label & 144& 14.4 & 490 & long label & 0.00 & 0\\\hline
&&&&500 &long label &98.63&10\\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{long label}&1,44.00 &&\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{long label}&1,44.00& \\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{long label}&1,44.00 &&\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{long label}&157.66 &\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Why column 5 text is pushed so far away ?
Why the inner tables (under header) don't spread for the full width of the multicolumn ?

Comment: for example in `\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{20}{p{0.5\textwidth}} @{}}` you have removed the 2 outer tabcolsep but still have 38\tabcolsep inter column space plus 1\textwidth width of the text content of p columns so you are specifying it to be 38\tabcolsep wider than \textwidth

Comment: We had a conversation about it here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583583/xltabular-not-producing-desired-result
The post got delayed so I made a new one.
Yes you are right that there are 8 columns but with your example in the post the layout is different.

Comment: Its a mistake from copy pasting. For the small font.
What is the proper way to do this table without multicolumn ? Multicolumn gives me an option to place vertical lines whenever I need them. Also with 8 columns I can not make a table which has different number of columns on each row - give that a certain column must be "small" like the д% column.

Comment: if you really want to define \smf, then as I say, just delete the space before `%` but simpler to use `\small` it is hard to know what font size you actually want as your documentclass is  `\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=18pt]{article}` but `article` does not have a `paper` or `fontsize` option

Comment: I will apply the suggested fixes. Most of the suggestions are unrelated with the table layout. The given answer produces a table with layout that has almost nothing to the original. I must just looking for a way to produce the exact same table like this in the picture.

Comment: It is hard to suggest how to lay out the table as the image shown clearly only has 8 columns, I spent sone effort on previpus answers coding it up in that way, perhaps I missed some feature, so another question is fine but as this just ignores all previous answers with this complicated array of multicolumns for every entry with no indication of where the additional columns need to be used. I can not guess what answer you want.

Comment: By "you have removed the 2 outer tabcolsep but still have 38\tabcolsep inter column space plus 1\textwidth width of the text content of p columns so you are specifying it to be 38\tabcolsep wider than \textwidth" you mean that I should remove 2\tabcolsep for each column ?

Comment: The additional columns are just chunks of the whole width. This way it just give me an option to spread them the way I want for each row. These 8 columns (yes you are right, the are indeed 8) are just fragmented into 20 columns. 
Then I will make a 8 column table like you suggested in the previous answer and will post it here.

Comment: I want to try your approach but there are things that I can't figure out why they work like that. I updated the original post @DavidCarlisle

Comment: `p{3cm}` means a parbox with text lines 3cm wide separted on each side by \tabcolsep space (plus the width of vertical rule on the right if you have rules) so a table that is `*{20}{p{3cm}}` is 20 times (3cm+2\tabcolsep) wide, similarly if you span two such columns you need to span the text and the inner column gap so you need `\multicolumn{2}{p{6cm+2\tabcolsep}` the actual calculations are not hard but if you change from 20 columns to 8 all the multicolumn use changes. So you need to decide that first.

Comment: I was talking about the example provided by you. There is no p type column. You define @{\extracolsep{\fill}}|*{8}{l|}@{} which is 8 times l type column.
After that there are 2 multicolumns and they contaion a tabular with 4 columns each, 4 rows.
All text in the column number 5 are pushed right for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, I would design your table as follows:

- consider most of comments below your question i.e. your second MWE
- for table I would use `xltabular`
- in columns with numbers I would use `S` column type
- form the most used multicolumn cells I would define new commands `\mcl` and `\mcll`
- in editor remove group separators for thousand (their inserting left to `siunitx`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,    % paper size
    margin=20mm % all margins are equal
        }
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % only needed with old latex installations
%\usepackage[defaultsans]{opensans} %font
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable, xltabular}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcll{m}{\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{#1}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcl{ m}{\multicolumn{2}{ l|}{#1}}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{greyCell}{RGB}{235,235,235}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4,
         group-separator={,}} 
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}% keep hline away from text
\small
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ *{2}{|S[table-format=3]
                                        |X
                                        |S[table-format=4.2]
                                        |S[table-format=2.1]}|
                                }
    \hline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{\textbf{Header}}   \\
\multicolumn{4}{|l}{
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lrl}
    Label   &           & 2020.07                   \\
    Label   & 146       & long variable test        \\
    Label   & 12        & variable variable variable\\
    Label   & 24568545  & long variable here
    \end{tabular}}
    &   \multicolumn{4}{l|}{
        \begin{tabular}{@{} ll}
        Label   &  long variable                \\
        Label   & 23                            \\
        Label   & Long variable long variable   \\
        Label   & 1,000.12
        \end{tabular}}          \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{greyCell}
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Label}}   & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Label}}\\  \hline
{label} & label         & {label}   & {d\%} & {label} & label         & {label} & {d\%} \\  \hline
104     & long variable & 1 000.00  & 14.4  & 455     & long variable & 777.20  & 0,4   \\  \hline
111     & long label    &   144.00  & 14.4  & 490     & long label    & 0.00    & 0     \\  \hline
        &               &           &       & 500     & long label    & 98.63   & 10    \\  \hline
\mcll{long label}        &   144.00  &       & \mcl{long label}  
                                                      & 1 144.00      &   \\  \hline
\mcll{long label}        &   144.00  &       & \mcl{long label} 
                                                      &   157.66      &   \\  \hline
    \end{xltabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. The layout is exactly what it needs to be. I get some error under This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex) The error is ! Missing number, treated as zero.
Originally I try to stick with longtable only. 
I did the exact same report with xltabular -> https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583484/xltabular-produces-error-in-combination-with-multicolumn-and-kill

Under This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.12) it works like a charm.

Comment: @LubomirBorisov, I use recent MikTeX installation and pdfLaTeX. I didn't investigate, what you try before, however, proposed solution works as expected (you complain about yours). It is not clear, why you need the `\kill` command in this table. I dont see any reason.

Comment: I used \kill in the MWE in the link because I used X type columns for the table preamble. For each row I used multicolumn for the entire row. This caused a problem - table didnt spread to full textwidth because it can not calculate the width of a single column. \kill solves that - it is written in the longtable docs."If a line is \killed, by using \kill rather than \\ at the end of the line,
it is used in calculating column widths, but removed from the final table"

Comment: @LubomirBorisov, in proposed solution, as you can see, this is not needed anymore.

Comment: Its not needed but I get errors with NewExpandableDocumentCommand . Actually its all so messed up in my head that I got to the point where I do not know what is going on. 
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Just 1 question. You use {2}* S X S S. Its the same as {2}* c X c c. 
Why do you use only 1 column type X ?

Comment: @LubomirBorisov, you can instead `S` column type use any other type. This is up to you, however, other types (except `d` defined in `dcolumn` package doesn't offer alignment at decimal points. In `xltabular` as well in `tabularx` had to be at least one column of `X` type or its derivatives.

Comment: @LubomirBorisov S is not the same as c it causes the decimal points to line up in the column.

Comment: @LubomirBorisov I added `\kill` to longtable as it was easy and I thought it might be useful in some cases but in 30 years of use I don't think I have ever seen any real use for it. I only suggested it in your earlier example as a work-around for the excessive use of `\multicolumn` which removed all of the original table specification, and that was a way to get back a row that did not have `\multicolumn` on every entry.   With a more reasonable table specification, as here, `\kill` is no use at all.

Comment: Thank you all for the effort! It works as it should be. Btw what is the proper way to vertical align in a X cell ? Or even align in l,c,r,X cells ?

Comment: @LubomirBorisov, use of `m{<width>}` type column (defined in `array` package) or at `tabularx`, you need redefined `X` column type as `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}`. I suggest you to make yourself more familiar with writing of tables by reading some introductory text about it. For example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables